# Why Greedy Coin Change Algorithm is not Showing right result for double values?

Tags: c, algorithm, greedy, coin-change

[image: Screenshot of my Output]

On the image the highlighted 0.03 should be 0.04 but showing 0.03 and coin needed should be 10 but showing 9

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    double coins[6] = {0.01,0.05,0.10,0.25,1,2};
    double ans[15];
    double V = 5.64;
    int j=0,i=5,Tcoin = 0;
    while(V>coins[0])
    {
        if(coins[i]<=V)
        {
            j = V/coins[i];
            //printf("%.2lf - %.2lf = %.2lf\n",V,j*coins[i],V-(j*coins[i]));//This is for testing purpose
            V = V-(j*coins[i]);
            Tcoin += j;
        }
        i--;
    }
    printf("Number of coin needed is: %d\n",Tcoin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Because of exactly this kind of problem, one should never use floating-point arithmetic for money.  For change-making and simple accounting, use integer cents for everything.  It can be necessary to use integers scaled to some fraction of a cent for calculations involving compound interest, but don't worry about that until you get there.

Comment: As there is only 2 digits after decimal points (in case of currency)..convert your money and corresponding denomination in integer multiplying with `100` and then proceed with the same algorithm. What you need at the end is the number of denominations..

Comment: Add a #define double int below <stdio>, multiply `V` and `coins` items by 100 and your program works